# Node.js sails.js pm2 ec2 instance error due to memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sails.js

I am currently running a basic website on an amazon EC2 t1.micro instance.

The application is built using sails.js / node.js and is booted up using pm2.

After a while I get the following message in the errors log file and the server crashes:

```
FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Could somebody help me with this issue?

Have I misconfigured something?

I am running:

Node version 5.9.0

NPM 3.7.3

Comment: what is the version of your node and npm?

Comment: I have added node / npm version above

Comment: Could you just be running out of available memory on your t1.micro instance? Perhaps you need to upgrade to a larger server?

Comment: I do wonder that. Is there any ways to check how much memory is / has been used? This is the first AWS / node.js site I have setup so am inexperienced.

Comment: use `pm2 monit` to display using  CPU an memory by your application.
More details her: [http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/monitoring/]